# JDBI running slow on remote database - Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, performance, jdbi

I am using a jdbi in a Java application to connect to a MySQL database. When I connect to a remote database the application runs really slow and when the database is on my local machine it runs really fast. I think the slow speed may be because I am re opening database connections ( jdbi Handle ). I have tried to share the Handle object but have not had any success. Below is a snippet of the code I am using. Is there someway I can get this to run as fast, or nearly as fast, as it does when running with a local database? Thanks.

```
try (Handle h = dbi.open()) {
  ...
  h.createQuery( sql ).first();
}
```

Comment: Do you use a connection pool like [Apache Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/)?

Comment: "Slow" = "hours"?  "100ms"?  Show us the generated SQL,. `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Comment: Thanks, have just added Apache Commons DBCP connection pooling and one page has gone from taking 40 seconds to 10 seconds, big improvement, this is with the remote db.
When using a local db, the same page takes just 2 seconds.

Pages run pretty quickly  when database and web app are on the same machine, mostly under 4 seconds. But when using the local db, without connection pooling, they can be anywhere up to about 90 seconds, although most are between 15 and 30 seconds.

Comment: Are you reconnecting to the database for each query?  If so, DO NOT.  Use one connection for all queries for the page.

Comment: I am still calling dbi.open() multiple times per page, will that still reconnect to the database even though I am now using Apache Commons DBCP connection pooling?

Comment: @brushsteve - Pooling helps with part of the cost, but not all.